# Infinite loop on ComponentWillMount ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, salesforce

I'm trying to use ReactJS on Salesforce but the queries are quite problematic

Take a look at this code, trying to make something cool to get all data but the while isn't stop, don't know why, please help me and feel free to ask me anything

```
componentWillMount(){
    let queryMore = true
    let offSet = 0
    let contents = []
    while(queryMore) {
      makeDeferredProvider()
      let contentObject = SObjectModel.deferredObject('Content')     
      let retrieveOptions = {
        limit: 10,
        where: { 
          Type__c: { eq: 'Image' }
        }
      }      
      offSet > 0 ? retrieveOptions.offset = offSet : ''      
      let contentPromise = contentObject.retrieve(retrieveOptions)
      contentPromise.then( records => {        
        records.forEach( record => {
          let item = {
            'name': record.get('Name'),
            'id': record.get('Id')
          }
          contents.push(item)
        })        
        records.length = 10 ? offSet += 10 : queryMore = false        
      }, error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
    this.setState({
      contents: contents
    })
  }
```

Comment: A while loop is synchronous and you're only setting queryMore to false after some async request meaning it's going to run a billion times before that and freeze up your browser. Start by fixing that - do the promises need to resolve in sequence or in parallel? for..of and Promise.all can be used to wait for multiple promises either in sequence or parallel

Comment: Thanks Dominic, can you give me a solution? I don't have too much experience with this and it will be very useful to learn it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async React will make this easier in the future, but right now you need to not block rendering while your promise is resolving.

Here's a high-level solution:

1. Stop using ComponentWillMount. It is being deprecated.
2. Stop using the while loop. It won't work with your promise. Get it working first then worry about queryMore later. See below.
3. Add a field in the component state called "loading" and default it to true.
4. Have a conditional in your render method to load a spinner (or NULL, or something) when "loading" equals true.
5. In ComponentDidMount*, call your request logic and set state WITHIN the function passed into the .then method after you retrieved all the contents. Make sure to set "loading" to false there.
6. The conditional in render should then render the contents.

Consider using JSForce (https://jsforce.github.io/) to connect to your object. It already has autoFetch logic included that could replace your queryMore logic.

* Using ComponentDidMount should work but it's probably a bad idea because the component will call out to SF on each render. You should probably use a handler and only call when you don't have the data in state or if you want to refresh for some other reason.

Comment: Thanks @CaseyBenko it's awesome! How can I get the '{!$API.Session_Id}' in ReactJS to create the new jsforce.Connection?

Comment: @elchiconube I don't know how your application is setup. I would recommend setting it as a parameter but you could just create a script before your import of your react code and assign the value to a value under document: Say `document.token = '{!$API.Session_Id}'`. Then reference that directly in the react code.